# I'm getting a SyntaxError | I'm learning from Learn Python The Hard Way

Tags: python-2.7

This is my code it's the exact same code as the pdf

```
states = [
"Oregon":"OR",
"Florida": "FL",
"California": "CA",
"New York": "NY",
"Michigan": "MI"
]

cities = [
"CA": "San Francisco",
"MI": "Detroit",
"FL": "Jacksonville"
]

cities["NY"] = "New York"
cities["OR"] = "Portland"

print "-" * 10
print "NY state has: ", cities["NY"]
print "OR state has: ", cities["OR"]

print "-" * 10
print "Michigan's abbreviation is: ", states["Michigan"]
print "Florida's abbreviation is: ", states["Florida"]

print "-" * 10
print "Michigan has: ", cities[states["Michigan"]]
print "Florida has: ", cities[states["Florida"]]

print "-" * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s is abbreviated %s", % (state, abbrev)

print "-" * 10
for abbrev, city in cities.items():
    print "%s has the city %s" % (abbrev, city)

print "-" * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s state is abbreviated %s and has city %s" % (
    state, abbrev, cities[abbrev])

print "-" * 10
state = states.get("Texas", None)

if not state:
    print "Sorry, no Texas."

city = cities.get("TX", "Does Not Exist")
print "The city for the state 'TX' is: %s" % city
```

This is my error i put into my terminal python ex39.py and i get this.

```
File "ex39.py", line 3
    "Oregon":"OR",
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i'm running macOS 10.13.6 Beta (17G47b)
MacBook (13-inch, Mid 2010)
Processor 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
Memory 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
Graphics NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB

Comment: Does LPTHW not teach the difference between lists and dicts? Might be time to find a new book...

Comment: I'll try to add the space but if that doesn't work i'll look for another book. Thanks for the info

edit - still getting the same error after adding the space. Time for a new book

Comment: Dupe, complete with LPTHW: [Python Dictionary Syntax Error \[learn python the hard way -ex39\]](//stackoverflow.com/q/44381389)

Comment: try substituting `[`s and `]`s with `{`s and `}`s for `states` and `cities`

Comment: Hi @vahdet that worked thanks and on line 39 i didn't have to do the , and it's working 100% fine now thanks.

Comment: how do i mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue here is when you use brackets [] it makes a list, like [1,2,3,4,5].
While 1-5 in that list are all in the same list, they don't directly interact with each other.
You're looking for a dictionary, which uses curly brackets {}. It takes a array of information, but it takes them in pairs of a key and its value.

So you need this

```
states = {
"Oregon":"OR",
"Florida": "FL",
"California": "CA",
"New York": "NY",
"Michigan": "MI"
}

cities = {
"CA": "San Francisco",
"MI": "Detroit",
"FL": "Jacksonville"
}
```

The first of the pair is they key, the second is the value.
Hope this helps! Happy coding!